# How can I only read the 'Applications and Services logs' using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-2.0, event-log

How can I only read the *Applications and Services logs* using PowerShell? I tried `Get-WinEvent`, but it also includes *Windows Logs*.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list of log names first and then only pass the desired log names to [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent):

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog Microsoft-Windows-* | Foreach-Object {Get-WinEvent -LogName $_.LogName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
```

Most of the logs from *Applications and Services logs* are prefixed by `Microsoft-Windows-`. You might need to adjust this filter according to your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Get-EventLog`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849834.aspx) allows you to specify a single log to retrieve via the `LogName` parameter.

Comment: `Get-EventLog` does not work for all 'Applications and Services logs'. Especially not for logs below *Microsoft > Windows* ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532034/11942268)).