# How can I read analytical Windows events from 'Applications and Services Logs' using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, event-log

I use [`Get-EventLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog) to read events. Using this cmdlet, I can successfully read the *System* and the *Security* event logs for example. I can also list all available logs by issuing the following command:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName * | Select-Object -Property Log
```

Output:

```
Log
---
Application
HardwareEvents
Internet Explorer
Key Management Service
OAlerts
Parameters
Security
State
System
Windows PowerShell
```

But this list does not contain all of the logs you can find under *Applications and Services logs*, e. g.: I'd like to read the events from this path that can be traversed inside the *Event Viewer*:

```
Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > DNS-Server > Analytical
```

I'm doing this on a Windows DNS-Server with *Show Analytic and Debug Logs* enabled under *View* and also a configured and enabled *Analytical* log for *DNS-Server*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Tl;dr:

Use [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent) instead and add the `-Oldest` parameter:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Analytical -Oldest
```

---

[`Get-EventLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog) is a legacy cmdlet to read the Windows event log and it cannot be used to read all available event logs (look for the note in the documentation of this cmdlet):

> `Get-EventLog` uses a Win32 API that is deprecated. The results may not be accurate. Use the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet instead.

With [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent) you can list all available logs using `Get-WinEvent -ListLog *` or you can filter for all DNS related logs:

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog *DNS* | Select-Object -Property LogName
```

Output:

```
LogName
-------
DNS Server
Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client/Operational
Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Audit
```

Add the `-Force` parameter to also see *Debug* and *Analytical* events:

```
LogName
-------
DNS Server
Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client/Operational
Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Analytical
Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Audit
```

You can read the events by passing those names to the `-LogName` parameter:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Audit
```

You'll get an error when trying to read the `Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Analytical` log:

```
Get-WinEvent : The Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Analytical event log can be read only in the forward chronological order because it is an analytical or a debug log. To see events from the Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Analytical event log, use the Oldest parameter in the command.
```

So just add `-Oldest` and you are good to go:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DNSServer/Analytical -Oldest
```